# Not recognizing `\begin{document}`

Tags: errors, syntax

I stumbled upon the following warning and error, consecutively. I see no reason why they would correlate.

---

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 447, version
               `2011/01/03' of package etoolbox,
               but only version
               `2009/08/06 v1.8 e-TeX tools for LaTeX'
               is available.
```

---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ...x}[2011/01/03]\AfterEndEnvironment 
                                                  {table}{\ltx@ifpackageload...
l.447 }
```

---

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.447 }
```

---

**Miminal working example**:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\tablewidth=\textwidth
        \begin{tabular}{ |l| }
            content \tablefootnote{footnote content.} 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: MWE compiled]

---

What causes pdflatex not to recognize `\begin{document}`?

Moreover, the footnote is not printed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Your problem is: Your version of `etoolbox` is *way* outdated.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes but that wasn't the question, the question was why does that trigger a missing document error.

Comment: It is always the first error you need to fix. `AtEndEnvironment` wasn't yet implemented in 2009, hence the error. The missing begin document is the next error because LaTeX now thinks it needs to typeset something, and `\begin{document}` wasn't seen yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is best to ignore every error after the first.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ...x}[2011/01/03]\AfterEndEnvironment 
                                                  {table}{\ltx@ifpackageload...
l.447 }
```

so TeX was reading `\AfterEndEnvironment{table}`

It gives the error that `\AfterEndEnvironment` is not defined, so if you do not stop there it carries on and sees  `{table}` but this is (now) just text in a group, not the argument to a command, so it starts to typeset a paragraph, and latex flags that as an errror as you are not supposed to have text before `\begin{document}`

Comment: The package `tablefootnote` isn't working properly; the footnote isn't printed. Is this caused by my outdated `etoolbox`?

Comment: @MusséRedi Yes, it is.

Comment: @MusséRedi yes of course it will not work at at all as the commands used are not defined.

Comment: Okay, well, that's it then. I can't install packages using an installing tool, since I don't have root or the proper write priviliges on this system; I can only download and extract the packages in my home folder. If I have to update all deprecated packages manually I'll be installing forever. I'll wait until I'm back on my own system, I guess. Or is there another way?

Comment: If you are using TexLive, you could use [tlmgr](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) in "user mode" to install the packages automatically, in your home folder...

Comment: @Stobor probably not actually. Given the age of etoolbox shown, it must be an old texlive whose repositories will now be frozen so the OP would have to install texlive 2016 which can not be done via tlmgr from an old version.

Comment: @MusséRedi you could switch to one of the online systems eg sharelatex

Comment: @Stobor Yeah well, tlmgr is not installed on this system, and I don't have the proper privileges to install it, or to install anything for that matter. All I can do is produce the .sty files from the .dtx files, or download the .sty files directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ShareLaTeX seems like a suitable solution. I'll try it!